# How to check a particular revision resides between the committed revsion range of a directoty in SVN using svn command?

Tags: svn

In my project, I am checking out a dirctory using SVN command line. While doing that, I have observed the following use case.
I have one root directory in SVN say "login". Under that I have two source directories "login-dev" and "login-test". Many commits are there in both the source directories. 
The head version in "login-dev" directory is "101". 
The head version in "login-dev" directory is "110". Hence the head version in root directory "login" is "110". 
When I tried to check out the source from "login-dev" directory using the revision "110", it checked out the "login-dev" source upto "101" as there is no such reversion called "110" in that direcoty. This is the default functionality of SVN.  
But in that case, I should say "no revision exists" message.  
 
So, how to check a particular revision resides between the committed revsion range of a directoty in SVN using SVN command?

Comment: "Subversion's revision numbers apply to the entire repository tree, not individual files", so to say "no revision exists" is not true, you should say "no changes exist for that revision".

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will change the message. But how to find the version not exist using command?

Comment: Does `svn log` give you the latest revision containing a change to one of the files within the subfolder?

Comment: Thank you so much. I have achieved it using 'svn log -r' command.